# Building Flask server - installation error code 1 (MarkupSafe-python setup.py egg_info)

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

First of all, I run on Python3.6 and trying to install Flask 1.1x.
(I don't wanna upgrade Python)
So, I'm into the active environment `venv` folder trying to install Flask 1.1x (apparently is the only one that can run on Python3.6).

The error is always the same:

```
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-ez13kjkb/MarkupSafe/setup.py", line 61, in <module>
        run_setup(True)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-ez13kjkb/MarkupSafe/setup.py", line 44, in run_setup
        ext_modules=ext_modules if with_binary else [],
      File "/home/deeman/server/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 129, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 121, in setup
        dist.parse_config_files()
      File "/home/deeman/server/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 494, in parse_config_files
        ignore_option_errors=ignore_option_errors)
      File "/home/deeman/server/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 106, in parse_configuration
        meta.parse()
      File "/home/deeman/server/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 382, in parse
        section_parser_method(section_options)
      File "/home/deeman/server/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 355, in parse_section
        self[name] = value
      File "/home/deeman/server/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 173, in __setitem__
        value = parser(value)
      File "/home/deeman/server/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 430, in _parse_version
        version = self._parse_attr(value)
      File "/home/deeman/server/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 305, in _parse_attr
        module = import_module(module_name)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'markupsafe'
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-ez13kjkb/MarkupSafe/
```

**What can I do to fix this, any ideas? Thanks**

Answer (score -1):

upgrading pip sort out my problem `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`